# Access to ViewEngines.Engines.FindView Method in not web context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have question about access to FindView Method in not web context,

```
public static bool ViewExists(ControllerContext ctx, string name)
{
        var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ctx, name, null);
        return result.View != null;
}
```

I want to render view to create static files (JavaScript files rendered  in Razor),

When I use this metod in web context (in controller action metod everythik is ok, but in test context I get exception

System.Web.HttpException : The application relative virtual path '~/Views/Test/New.aspx' cannot be made absolute, because the path to the application is not known.

How I would use (moq)  ControllerContext in not web context to Render Razor View ?

Comment: Consider using RazorEngine.

Comment: RazorEngine isn't the best solution, because a have a lot of partials, better should be render full view